# How can I emit socket.io messages from Redis rq-scheduler task?

Tags: python, flask, redis, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm using flask and socket.io to build an app that queries an external API every 10 seconds, and emits the response to the users.

I've set up rq-scheduler to run a function every 10 seconds to query an API. I'd like to emit a socket.io message from this job, but I can't figure out how to do that, or what best practices are.

I see in the flask-socket.io docs, [emitting from an external process](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#emitting-from-an-external-process), but this example is very limited. Is there a clear example of how to actually emit an event from an external process? Does the code written in the docs go in the rq task, or in the flask server code?
Do I need to instantiate a socket.io server every time the task is run? How does the task know about socket.io otherwise?

I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction here. If there is a more robust example that would be awesome.

Comment: Yes, you have to instantiate a `SocketIO` object in every task, and pass the URL of your message queue so that it can communicate with the Socket.IO server. You will not be running the server on it though, this object is only used to emit.